# Sending device to device push notifications over server with nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I want to build a server using nodejs:

1. to send push notifications between groups of devices
2. Messages of a group should not reach devices of the other groups
3. An admin (eg. in an institute) should be able to create a group

I already created a solution using onesignal where one device sends a message to onesignal which then transfers it to all selected devices. 
There all we had to do was sending a request:

```
server.post('/', function (req, res) {
myClient.sendNotification(firstNotification, function (err, httpResponse, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong...');
    } else {
        console.log(data, httpResponse.statusCode);
    }
});
```

});

But I don't want to be dependent on third party software. This functionality should now run over my local server.

Can you give me some tips and ideas how to go about that? (architecture, data management)?

Best Regards

ZAtrue

Comment: Please include what code you have tried. Also, have you looked into websockets? See socket.io for example.

Comment: yes we did, but how exactly is the push notification transmitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should look into Socket.io.

On your client side you can listen for broadcasts a socket sends and react to it by (for example) firing a push notification on your device.

I would recommend to look at the socket.io [documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and the provided examples.

Regarding your groups, you could look into socket.io's [namespace and rooms](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).